# MongoDB rename collection with a dynamic name

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing a lot of data into a temp collection, after it finishes I want to rename it, but I  have the name only at runtime.

The renaming command is:

```
db.some_collection_temp.renameCollection('some_collection');
```

I don't know the `some_collection` name, I have it in a variable, so I do:

```
db[collName + '_temp'].renameCollection(collName);
```

That doesn't work

Error: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'renameCollection' of undefined`

Comment: What language and driver are you using?

Comment: I'm doing it in NodeJS using MongoJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoJS you can call [`rename`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#rename) on the collection:

```js
db.collection(collName + '_temp').rename(collName, function (err, collection){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Awesome!, that worked out fine, I tried that with renameCollection method instead of rename hehe, did you take that from Docs somewhere?, I would appreciate a link, cause I also have to send a "dropTarget":true. Thanks!

Comment: @pjnovas Keep in mind that renameCollection won't copy indexes, so you'll have to recreate them if your application relies on them.